# Как оставить на сайте только мобильную верстку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт, у которого есть адаптивная верстка под разные устройства. Требуется сделать так, чтобы на любом устройстве (телефон, планшет, компьютер) открывалась только мобильная версия сайта. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В медиа-запросе прописать максимальный размер экрана для мобильных корректировок. На пример - @media(max-width: 3350px) для мобильных устройств. Костыльно, думаю, но все же, как вариант.

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov вы не учитываете, что css может иметь концепты `mobile-first` или `desktop-first`.

Comment: @NoSkill, я предположил, что автор хочет просто мобильную верстку (мобильное меню и т.д.) на любых экранах, невзирая на ширину общего контента.

Comment: В общем случае простого решения здесь нет. Если сайт небольшой, то придется проанализировать все css media query. Если используется концепты `mobile-first`, то из css нужно убрать все `@media`. Если используется концепт `desktop-first` - тут посложнее, придется выносить все изнутри `@media` наружу. Также на сайте может быть управляющий javascript, который может учитывать @media, его тоже ридется перепахать.

Comment: @NoSkill, всё так и есть. Пришлось перепахать все media чтобы получить нужный результат. Хотел бы отметить Ваш комментарий как ответ, потому что другого способа по крайней мере ни гугл ни документация не дают, только не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Ограничьте ширину сайта, например 500px, вёрстка сама подстроится, если уже умеет

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Ширина 500px</h1>
      <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут, рыбные тексты. Раз, заманивший они. Это алфавит переулка гор, большой своего предложения своих возвращайся все? Рукопись, грамматики подзаголовок снова дорогу страна за свое толку вершину. Маленькая заглавных великий рекламных от всех текста переписали решила, языком там лучше однажды необходимыми коварный рукописи проектах то знаках оксмокс большой составитель дал переулка. Это безорфографичный заглавных путь. Свой сбить, толку щеке великий реторический речью букв то это оксмокс дорогу. Скатился даль проектах о безорфографичный, выйти вопроса текстами пояс буквоград. Предупреждал вдали которой родного меня от всех домах текст свой щеке, моей переписывается наш диких текста языкового, он речью дорогу, языком по всей власти эта последний правилами? Ipsum, силуэт подпоясал пор предложения знаках необходимыми там, образ живет мир деревни возвращайся своих пустился наш свой первую lorem рекламных оксмокс безорфографичный. Путь толку последний все, залетают ее над рукопись? Имеет своих за диких большой запятой, вопрос взгляд инициал силуэт на берегу рекламных, пустился продолжил приставка деревни прямо агентство речью дорогу путь использовало предложения если языком жаренные пунктуация осталось его. Составитель ему буквоград но он семь текстами ipsum осталось напоивший рукопись подзаголовок снова она дал дороге свою выйти, приставка имеет пояс большой родного. Жизни, сих переписывается, своих заголовок возвращайся пояс толку, власти там домах свой живет щеке родного которой путь семантика о одна переулка заманивший повстречался снова буквоград. Повстречался пунктуация ipsum деревни, послушавшись злых скатился всеми которой это буквенных они эта знаках осталось. Вершину рукопись переулка большого продолжил единственное коварных подпоясал буквоград вопрос большой щеке родного маленькая, имени заглавных, над страну повстречался послушавшись своего текстами, вскоре они агентство от всех. Пунктуация назад силуэт инициал парадигматическая на берегу. Осталось злых снова знаках прямо коварных реторический, единственное свое взобравшись одна текстами ты. Букв своего взгляд но до ты своих безорфографичный агентство, вопрос домах. Дорогу, lorem. Щеке рыбного которой вопрос заглавных сих осталось дорогу, инициал за решила, курсивных власти.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение )

Comment: Ограничить ширину некоего `wrapper` - это не то же самое, что уменьшить ширину `viewport` от которого как раз зависят все @media. Это решение ошибочное, если сайт собран на @media. Автор скорее всего имеет в виду не резиновый сайт, а именно мобильную и десктоп верстки (которые явно отличаются).

Comment: Это решение для изначальной верстки в mobile, а тут уже есть адаптивная верстка.